# Why does importing a specific subpackage module's method in the subpackage's __init__.py populate the package namespace with the subpackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

***I am using Python 3.9.10***

I understand that the question posed is rather verbose and confusing, however I couldn't think of a  better way to phrase it, so please allow me to illustrate the problem below:

I have a package, `test_import`, with the following structure:

```
test_import/
├── __init__.py
├── moduleA.py
└── moduleB/
   ├── __init__.py
   └── moduleB.py
```

`test_import/__init__.py` contains the following:

```py
from . import moduleA
from . import moduleB
```

`test_import/moduleA.py` contains the following:

```py
def test_func_module_a(s: str):
    print(f"test_import.moduleA.test_func_module_a        : {s}")
```

`test_import/moduleB/moduleB.py` contains the following:

```py
def test_func_module_b(s: str):
    print(f"test_import.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b: {s}")
```

And, finally, `test_import/moduleB/__init__.py` contains the following:

```py
from .moduleB import test_func_module_b
```

Lastly, with `test_import` in my `$PYTHONPATH`, I have the a python file, `test_main.py`, which imports and uses the (not-so-useful) `test_import` library:

```py
import test_import as ti

ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a("ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a")
ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b("ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b")
ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b("ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b")
```

When I run `test_main.py`, I expect to see the following:

```sh
my.username@myMac:Desktop$ python3 test_main.py 
test_import.moduleA.test_func_module_a        : ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a
test_import.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b: ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my.username/Desktop/test_import_main.py", line 11, in <module>
    ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b("ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b")
AttributeError: module 'test_import.moduleB' has no attribute 'moduleB'
```

I expect to see this because in `test_import/__init__.py`, I have only imported the specific method, `test_func_module_b` , into the namespace belonging to `test_import.moduleB`. I have not imported the `moduleB.py` module in `test_import/moduleB/__init__.py` i.e. `from . import moduleB`.

However, when I run `test_main.py`, I get the following, without any namespace-related AttributeError raised:

```sh
my.username@myMac:Desktop$ python3 test_main.py 
test_import.moduleA.test_func_module_a        : ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a
test_import.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b: ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b
test_import.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b: ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b
```

i.e. no AttributeError related to the `test_import.moduleB` namespace.

This is confusing because (as I said above), I did not import `moduleB.py` into `test_import.moduleB`'s namespace.

If I leave `test_import/__init__.py` as an empty file, and run `test_main.py`, `AttributeError`s are raised for both of the following lines, related to the absence of either in the subpackage's (`test_import.moduleB`) namespace, i.e.:

```sh
my.username@myMac:Desktop$ python3 test_import_main.py 
test_import.moduleA.test_func_module_a        : ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my.username/Desktop/test_import_main.py", line 10, in <module>
    ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b("ti.moduleB.test_func_module_b")
AttributeError: module 'test_import.moduleB' has no attribute 'test_func_module_b'
```

and

```sh
my.username@myMac:Desktop$ python3 test_main.py 
test_import.moduleA.test_func_module_a        : ti.moduleA.test_func_module_a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my.username/Desktop/test_import_main.py", line 11, in <module>
    ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b("ti.moduleB.moduleB.test_func_module_b")
AttributeError: module 'test_import.moduleB' has no attribute 'moduleB'
```

Could anyone shed some light on how Python's import system has achieved this?

PS - As there have been so many import-related questions on StackOverflow, I expect there to be similar questions. However, I have been unable to find answers to this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python encounters a *submodule* as part of an import (the `y` in `from x.y import z` (absolute) or `from .y import z` (relative)), it will place a reference to the submodule in the parent module's namespace. This is outlined in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism [...] a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.
> [...]
> The invariant holding is that if you have `sys.modules['spam']` and `sys.modules['spam.foo']` [...] the latter must appear as the `foo` attribute of the former.